# What does "see docstring of the instance object for more information" mean

Tags: scipy, instance, docstring

I feel like this is a dumb question, but when I'm in an IPython notebook and I do help on some numpy/scipy function, like say stat.norm.rvs, it frequently says, about *args and **kargs, "see docstring of the instance object for more information".  How do I see this docstring if not with help(stat.norm.rvs)?

Answer (score 9):

Don't feel dumb; sometimes it is hard to find the information you are looking for, especially when starting out. Moreover, much of the docstrings in `scipy.stats` are autogenerated, so they are somewhat generic, not custom-tailored. The good news is, once you undestand how to manipulate on distribution, all the others are basically the same since *they share the same interface*.

Let's work through an example. Since you are using IPython (great!), we can also
use the question mark after an object, e.g. `obj?`, to find out more about the
object. This shows the docstring, like `help(obj)`, plus other useful info such
as its type, where it is defined, and (for callables) its call signature.

It helps to have a picture of how things are organized. `scipy.stats` is a module:

```
In [386]: from scipy import stats
```

The module docstring lists many kinds of distributions.

```
In [394]: stats?
...
Continuous distributions
========================
   ...
   alpha             -- Alpha
   anglit            -- Anglit
   arcsine           -- Arcsine
   beta              -- Beta
   betaprime         -- Beta Prime
   ...
   norm              -- Normal (Gaussian)
```

There are two main classes -- `stats.rv_continuous` and `stats.rv_discrete`.
Each of these distributions listed in the `stats` docstring is an **instance** of
one of these two classes. `stats.norm` for example, is an [instance of
`stats.norm_gen`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L191) which is a [subclass of `stats.rv_continuous`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L108):

```
In [14]: type(stats.norm).mro()
Out[14]: 
[scipy.stats._continuous_distns.norm_gen,
 scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_continuous,
 scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_generic,
 object]
```

---

Notice that `stats.norms.rvs` is an **instancemethod** :

```
In [387]: stats.norm.rvs?
Type:        instancemethod
String form: <bound method norm_gen.rvs of <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.norm_gen object at 0x7f1479ba2690>>
```

So when later it says

> The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the **instance**
>       object for more information).

it is saying there is more information in the docstring of `stats.norm`:

```
In [401]: stats.norm?
Docstring:
A normal continuous random variable.

The location (loc) keyword specifies the mean.
The scale (scale) keyword specifies the standard deviation.
...
Methods
-------
``rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)``
    Random variates.
```

From this description you can see that `stats.norm.rvs(loc=10, scale=2, size=5)` will return 5 random variates with mean 10 and standard deviation 2:

```
In [402]: stats.norm.rvs(loc=10, scale=2, size=5)
Out[402]: array([  9.82454792,   8.52106712,   7.33889233,   8.73638555,  10.90927226])
```

Alternatively, `stats.norm` is also callable -- you can pass the `loc` and `scale` "shape" parameters [to "freeze" those parameters](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy-stats-norm) into the distribution. What you get back is called a "frozen distribution".  For example, you can create a normal distribution with mean 10 and standard devation 2:

```
In [403]: norm = stats.norm(10, 2)
```

and now call the frozen distribution's `rvs` method to obtain 5 random variates:

```
In [404]: norm.rvs(5)
Out[404]: array([  7.21018883,  12.98978919,  10.99418761,  11.2050962 ,   8.27780614])
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and informative explanation.  I don't feel dumb at all anymore.  Even after reading your explanation through a few times I wasn't still entirely clear.  I kept thinking "instance?  what instance?"  And in fact, if stats.norm were in fact the name of just a subclass, then it would not be really correct to refer to it as an instance.

Comment: I should add, because I thought `norm` was a subclass not an [instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29).  So finally I decided to have a peak at the scipy source code.  Well, in fact `norm` is actually an instance... `norm = norm_gen(name="norm")`.  Wow, didn't think that the scipy folks would expect a user to realize that!

Comment: Right! `norm = norm_gen(name="norm")` makes `norm` an instance of `norm_gen`. Even though [the docs say](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html), "As an **instance** of the `rv_continuous` class, `norm` object inherits from it a collection of generic methods..." it is easy to miss.

Comment: You are quite correct.  I did completely miss that "As an instance of...".  It was easy to miss, but I should also slow down and read a bit more closely.    I've been trying to translate what I've learned taking some MOOCs in R to Python/Scipy and I guess I've gotten a bit impatient.  It'd sure be great if there as many quality MOOCs for statistics and machine learning using Python as there are in  R.