# Passing distribution parameters as an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a need to generate many samples at once, that have same distribution type, but different parameters. I tried the following code:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
size = 5
sample = sps.norm.rvs(size=size, loc=a)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/<me>/.pyenv/versions/study/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 933, in rvs
args, loc, scale, size = self._parse_args_rvs(*args, **kwds)
File "<string>", line 6, in _parse_args_rvs
File "/Users/<me>/.pyenv/versions/study/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 847, in _argcheck_rvs
raise ValueError("size does not match the broadcast shape of "
ValueError: size does not match the broadcast shape of the parameters.
```

Thinking that maybe the size parameter should be also numpy 1D array of size 3, I did the following:

```
size = np.array([5,5,5])
```

Only to be greeted with the same exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/<me>/.pyenv/versions/study/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 933, in rvs
args, loc, scale, size = self._parse_args_rvs(*args, **kwds)
File "<string>", line 6, in _parse_args_rvs
File "/Users/<me>/.pyenv/versions/study/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 847, in _argcheck_rvs
raise ValueError("size does not match the broadcast shape of "
ValueError: size does not match the broadcast shape of the parameters.
```

Thinking that the documentation may be the answer, I did `help(sps.norm.rvs)`, to see the following:

```
arg1, arg2, arg3,... : array_like
    The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the
    instance object for more information).
```

I am not quite sure what the instance object is, so I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391970/what-does-see-docstring-of-the-instance-object-for-more-information-mean) question, and typed in `help(sps.norm)`, only to see that the answer is still unknown:

```
rvs(self, *args, **kwds)
  Random variates of given type.

  Parameters
  ----------
  arg1, arg2, arg3,... : array_like
      The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the
      instance object for more information).
```

Where can I find the required docstring, and, more importantly, how do I generate several samples at once with different parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rvs` method does broadcast, but the `size` argument must be the final size of the result.  If you have 3 location values, and you want to draw 5 samples per location value, you can use `size=(5, 3)`:

```
In [118]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [119]: a = np.array([1, 2, 4])

In [120]: norm.rvs(loc=a, scale=0.05, size=(5, 3))
Out[120]: 
array([[ 1.01730871,  2.01713648,  3.96844145],
       [ 0.96102855,  2.03925685,  3.93189097],
       [ 0.98847545,  1.98229486,  4.00753205],
       [ 0.99843892,  1.95899283,  3.98745337],
       [ 1.01457605,  1.97508746,  4.07114077]])
```

Be sure that you have at least scipy version 0.18.0 if you use this technique.  Previous versions had [a bug](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2069) in the broadcast behavior of the `rvs` method.

Here's a more complicated example:

Suppose you have 3 location values and 2 scale values, and for each pair,
you want to draw 5 samples.  Also, you want the shape of the result to
be (3, 2, 5).

Here are the location and scale arrays:

```
In [136]: a = np.array([1, 2, 4])

In [137]: s = np.array([0.05, 0.001])
```

We'll use `size=(3, 2, 5)` in the call to `rvs()`, so we have to make
the shapes of the `loc` and `scale` arguments consistent with the numpy
broadcasting rules.  The `loc` shape will have to be `(3, 1, 1)`,
and the `scale` shape will have to be `(1, 2, 1)`. (The shape `(2, 1)`
would also be consistent.)  To add those trivial dimensions to `a`,
we can index with `None`, `a[:,None,None]`, or we can use the `reshape`
method, `a.reshape(-1, 1, 1)`.  We can do the same for the `s` when
we use it as the `scale` argument.

So the call to `rvs()` is

```
In [138]: samples = norm.rvs(loc=a[:,None,None], scale=s[None,:,None], size=(3, 2, 5))

In [139]: samples.shape
Out[139]: (3, 2, 5)

In [140]: samples[0, 0]  # loc=1, scale=0.05
Out[140]: array([ 1.0343322 ,  1.06019143,  0.95058855,  1.04184266,  1.00383671])

In [141]: samples[2, 1]  # loc=4, scale=0.001
Out[141]: array([ 4.00106506,  4.00066642,  3.99801552,  3.99829284,  4.00114079])
```